# Can I hide the birthdays of people I don't follow on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I would like to hide the birthdays notifications on the right of people that are friends but I'm not following. Would be that possible? And if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. All birthdays will be shown regardless of subscription setting.